# Dropdown with search - for optgroup up and down keys from it is not working

Tags: html, jquery-select2

`

```
<div class="form-control">
    <label for="optSymbol" style="color:green">Select2 + Search</label>
    <select id="optSymbol" class="optSymbol">
        <optgroup label="veg">
            
       <option>banana
        </option>
        <option>mango
        </option><option>guvva
        </option>
        <option>pickel
        </option>
        <option>apple
        </option>
        <option>pineapple
        </option>
         </optgroup>
         
         <optgroup label="games">
              <option>kabbadi
        </option>
         <option>cricket
        </option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#optSymbol').select2({});

$("body").on('keydown', ".select2", function(e) {
    var KEYS = { UP: 38, DOWN: 40 };
    var sel = $(this).closest('.select2-container').parent().find('select');
    var selectedOption = $(sel).find(':selected');
    var optgroup = selectedOption.closest('optgroup');
    var optionsInOptgroup = optgroup.find('option');
    var currentIndex = optionsInOptgroup.index(selectedOption);

    if (e.keyCode === KEYS.DOWN) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentIndex < optionsInOptgroup.length - 1) {
            newValue = optionsInOptgroup.eq(currentIndex + 1).val();
        }
    } else if (e.keyCode === KEYS.UP) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            newValue = optionsInOptgroup.eq(currentIndex - 1).val();
        }
    }

    if (newValue !== undefined) {
        $(sel).val(newValue).trigger('change');
    }
 });
});

 </script>
```

`

It is working fine for normal options from dropdown but when I have optgroup with options then it is not working when I press up and down keys from keyboard it is only changing with current group when other group encounters, then it is not going to another group.

Please fix the issue.